# Applying Bohr model on a system electron and positron

Tags: atomic-physics

> Consider a hypothetical particle consisting an electron and positron revolving around their common centre of mass. If the Bohr Model is applied on this particle, then find the value of Rydberg constant $R$ in terms of $R_H$.
>   What property of an electron in a given shell will be identical for the hypothetical particle and Hydrogen atom?
>   1. Velocity
>   2. Radius
>   3. de Broglie Wavelength
>   4. Kinetic Energy

The way I thought about it is since the positive charge of hydrogen nucleus and positron is same, the value of $Z=1$ in $R$ will be the same has hydrogen and the only difference will be in the reduced mass, which will be equal to $ m_e/2$ (the mass of electron). Since Rydberg constant is directly proportional to the reduced mass, $R = R_H/2$. And since the mass of electron is almost the same as a positron, the kinetic energy will be equally divided among them equally so Kinetic Energy, velocity and de Broglie wavelength will be different and radius must be same(according to options). Am I right about it? And in case I am, why is the radius equal for both cases?

Comment: have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium , also http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-61281-7_13#page-1

Comment: @annav It says that frequencies of spectral lines are half that of hydrogen atom, which means that rydberg constant will be half just as I thought. Also the energy levels are half that of hydrogen which means K.E. will be half too and so will be velocity and de Broglie wavelength. So the radius will be same and I think I know the reason for it. So am I correct?

Comment: If you look at the second link, where it says "look inside" it says that the radius is twice as large as for hydrogen

Comment: @annav Then what property will be identical?

Comment: I cannot know without calculating each quantity, and am not going to do it as am rusty in calculations. It is possible that the system one has to consider  for the comparison is the system where the positron is at rest.  It may be the debroglie, since the positron will be assumed motionless all the kinetic energy should be on the electron in that system. I may be wrong.

Comment: @annav If we assume the positron to be motionless, then would it be against the statement in the question, "revolving around their common centre of mass"?

Comment: You are correct. It does say "revolving around the center of mass". Where did you get the problem from?

Comment: http://s3.amazonaws.com/cramster-resource/60181_quizsolu1.pdf ,look for positronium

Comment: @annav It was on a test. It's pre-college level though.